# AWSLogs Resource Limit Exceeded - serverless `cloudwatchLog` event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to add the cloudwatchLog event to my lambda function and am getting an unexpected error. The error message is not very descriptive. Does anyone know what is going on?

Config:

```
functions:
  helloWorld:
    handler: dist/handlers/index.helloWorld
    events:
      - cloudwatchLog:
          logGroup: '/aws/lambda/serverless-test-package-4-dev-supWorld'
```

Error Message:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

An error occurred: HelloWorldLogsSubscriptionFilterCloudWatchLog1 - 
Resource limit exceeded. (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error 
Code: LimitExceededException; Request ID: e30b438c-a654-11e8-837a-7f86cfddec76).

Get Support --------------------------------------------
   Docs:          docs.serverless.com
   Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
   Forums:        forum.serverless.com
   Chat:          gitter.im/serverless/serverless

Your Environment Information -----------------------------
   OS:                     linux
   Node Version:           8.11.3
   Serverless Version:     1.26.1
```

Comment: Have you seen: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html? The second row in the table, CreateLogGroup, seems to align with your error.

Comment: @ninge it was actually the `Subscription Filter` constraint, the last row of that table, that was resulting in the error. Thank you for linking the docs.

Answer (score 26):

The problem was that there was already a lambda which had the CloudWatchLog event subscription. AWS limits each CloudWatch Log Group to a maximum of one subscription, as specified by [the last row of this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html).

Comment: I confirm. You can mark the answer as validated I think :)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you have to remove the already attached subscription from the log group. Just removing the `cloudwatchLog` event from lambda and deploying will remove the subscription from the log group. You can then add the `cloudwatchLog` event for the required log group and deploy it again.